# How does Codesandbox implement resizable grid of components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How does Codesandbox implement resizable windows. I want to implement a user resizable grid in React just like VS-Code or CodeSandbox allows to.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I found a solution for this, it was to use the react-simple-resizer npm module

Check out its docs they'll be able to help you.

Here's the example that they have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Section, Bar } from 'react-simple-resizer';
 
export default () => (
  <Container style={{ height: '500px' }}>
    <Section style={{ background: '#d3d3d3' }} minSize={100}/>
    <Bar size={10} style={{ background: '#888888', cursor: 'col-resize' }} />
    <Section style={{ background: '#d3d3d3' }} minSize={100} />
  </Container>
);
```